# Extract data from sdf file in bash environment

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to extract data from an SDF file.

I want to save the `>  <Name>` and `>  <SCORE.INTER>` values in a .tsv file.
Is there any way for a quick solution e.g. via awk?
Thanks in advance.

The SDF file consists of thousands of Block's. One block of the file looks like this:

```
ZINC000169748276

 38 39  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   11.2318    3.6419   22.3134 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.5621    3.7685   22.2617 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.0725    5.1806   22.3121 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   10.8850    6.0303   22.4462 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.4310    2.6268   22.1614 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.9848    1.3691   22.0592 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.2548    4.7608   21.1375 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.1479    3.7322   21.1132 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.7728    2.5366   21.8185 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.9539    4.4605   22.4534 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.8873    0.1824   21.9500 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.5117    1.6060   20.8656 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.2544    6.2009   22.3970 N   0  0  0  0  0  0
   10.3635    4.7178   22.4055 N   0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.4254    5.4429   22.2718 N   0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.7646   -0.5167   20.6443 N   0  3  0  0  0  0
    6.5529   -4.6019   19.9460 O   0  5  0  0  0  0
    8.2203   -4.0310   21.8048 O   0  5  0  0  0  0
    6.8149    1.6459   17.3793 O   0  5  0  0  0  0
    5.4231   -2.1179   18.5726 O   0  5  0  0  0  0
   10.1403    7.0090   22.5243 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7155   -3.6365   22.1679 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.6431    1.8811   19.7228 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.0295   -0.6218   20.7059 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.7342    3.0736   22.7475 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.0324    4.2091   21.8626 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.1857    1.9631   19.5323 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.0232   -2.2197   20.5667 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.0081   -0.1966   19.1450 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.8632   -3.7464   21.1697 P   0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.7991    1.4009   18.8725 P   0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.9605   -1.3044   19.7288 P   0  0  0  0  0  0
   15.0444    4.6730   22.2089 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.7148    6.3890   22.3078 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.3405   -1.3642   20.6292 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.0706    0.0896   19.8769 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.7928   -0.7891   20.4667 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.3352    3.5319   21.8055 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  2  0  0  0
  1 14  1  0  0  0
  2  3  1  0  0  0
  2  5  1  0  0  0
  3 13  2  0  0  0
  3 15  1  0  0  0
  4 13  1  0  0  0
  4 14  1  0  0  0
  4 21  2  0  0  0
  5  6  2  0  0  0
  6 11  1  0  0  0
  7  8  1  0  0  0
  7 10  1  0  0  0
  8  9  1  0  0  0
  8 26  1  0  0  0
  9 12  1  0  0  0
  9 25  1  0  0  0
 10 14  1  0  0  0
 10 25  1  0  0  0
 11 16  1  0  0  0
 12 27  1  0  0  0
 17 30  1  0  0  0
 18 30  1  0  0  0
 19 31  1  0  0  0
 20 32  1  0  0  0
 22 30  2  0  0  0
 23 31  2  0  0  0
 24 32  2  0  0  0
 27 31  1  0  0  0
 28 30  1  0  0  0
 28 32  1  0  0  0
 29 31  1  0  0  0
 29 32  1  0  0  0
 15 33  1  0  0  0
 15 34  1  0  0  0
 16 35  1  0  0  0
 16 36  1  0  0  0
 16 37  1  0  0  0
 26 38  1  0  0  0
M  END
>  <CHROM.1>
2.74804207,-114.83879868,178.63419806,-11.86097681,-104.18799792,-175.61867989
-82.60305529,-167.43897154,58.52671946,-50.63759561,-111.24083331,101.74294800
8.69431853,1.29062552,20.98254072,-0.89039136,0.27787279,-3.08051579

>  <Name>
ZINC000169748276

>  <RI>
1.76083e+07


>  <Rbt.Executable>
rbdock/0.1.0

>  <Rbt.Library>
librxdock.so/0.1.0

>  <SCORE>
-41.7582

>  <SCORE.INTER>
-41.8551

>  <SCORE.INTER.CONST>
1

>  <SCORE.INTER.POLAR>
-4.96496

>  <SCORE.INTER.REPUL>
0

>  <SCORE.INTER.ROT>
10

>  <SCORE.INTER.VDW>
-40.3742

>  <SCORE.INTER.norm>
-1.30797

>  <SCORE.INTRA>
0.0969082

>  <SCORE.INTRA.DIHEDRAL>
-5.79141

>  <SCORE.INTRA.DIHEDRAL.0>
19.5819

>  <SCORE.INTRA.POLAR>
0

>  <SCORE.INTRA.POLAR.0>
0

>  <SCORE.INTRA.REPUL>
0

>  <SCORE.INTRA.REPUL.0>
0

>  <SCORE.INTRA.VDW>
2.99261

>  <SCORE.INTRA.VDW.0>
-5.2787

>  <SCORE.INTRA.norm>
0.00302838

>  <SCORE.RESTR>
0

>  <SCORE.RESTR.CAVITY>
0

>  <SCORE.RESTR.norm>
0

>  <SCORE.SYSTEM>
0

>  <SCORE.SYSTEM.CONST>
0

>  <SCORE.SYSTEM.DIHEDRAL>
0

>  <SCORE.SYSTEM.norm>
0

>  <SCORE.heavy>
32

>  <SCORE.norm>
-1.30494

$$$$
```

The .tsv file should look like this:

```
ZINC000169748276    -41.8551
ZINC000079214514    -41.7892
ZINC000195993528    -40.9293
```

Comment: awk is mainly used to process a file line by line, based on the content of certain fields in the lines. Your problem does not fit well to awk, although in theory you can do it in any programming language (including awk).

Comment: This is a perfect fit for awk. Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with concise, testable sample input (i.e. multiple small blocks, not 1 large block), expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '
    /^>/ { tag=$2; next }
    NF { f[tag]=$1 }
    $0 == "$$$$" { print f["<Name>"], f["<SCORE.INTER>"] }
' file
ZINC000169748276        -41.8551
```

The above assumes a line containing `$$$$` is what's used to separate your input records.

Note that with this approach of first creating an array (`f[]` above) that maps the tags/names to their values you can print whatever values you like in whatever order you like, convert the whole thing to a CSV, compare values with other values by their names, etc. e.g. you can write things like this to analyze areas of your data and output reports, etc:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    /^>/ { tag=$2; next }
    NF { f[tag]=$1 }
    $0 == "$$$$" {
        if (    (f["<SCORE.INTRA.POLAR>"] >= f["<SCORE.INTRA.REPUL>"]) &&
                (f["<SCORE.RESTR.CAVITY>"] == 27) ) {
            print f["<Name>"]
            for ( tag in f ) {
                if ( tag ~ /SCORE/ ) {
                    print f[tag]
                }
            }
        }
    }
' file
```

If you're ever considering using `getline` then please see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for why it's usually the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why `awk`?

```
Prompt> grep -A 1 -i "<NAME>" test.txt | tail -n 1
ZINC000169748276
Prompt> grep -A 1 -i "<SCORE.INTER>" test.txt | tail -n 1
-41.8551
```

As you see, `grep` is far easier.

`-A 1` means "also take the next 1 line(s)".

After some discussion, this is the final solution:

```
grep -A 1 -i "<SCORE.INTER>" test.sdf | grep -v '^>' | grep -v '^--' >> results
```

Comment: Hello @Dominique, thank you very much that is already very helpful. However, as the file consists of thousands of blocks (one block shown in my example), I am wondering if it is possible to save only the line below `>  <SCORE.INTER>` . As using `grep -A 1 -i "<NAME>" test.txt` gives me `>  <SCORE.INTER>
-41.8551
--
>  <SCORE.INTER>
-41.7892
--
>  <SCORE.INTER>
-40.9293
--
>  <SCORE.INTER>
-40.725
--
>  <SCORE.INTER>
-40.6795
-- > ...`

Comment: You can grep on ">  <SCORE.INTER>" as you wish, I'm not sure what you mean exactly (maybe it's clearer if you just edit your question.

Comment: @lenskapopenska you could pipe a `| grep -v '^>'` to the first grep

Comment: Regarding the block's i hope it is clearer now in my original question. I would like to save only the values in the line below the `>  <SCORE.INTER>` item.  of each block. However, as stated above using `grep -A 1 -i "<NAME>" test.txt` still gives me both lines: `<SCORE.INTER> -41.8551` .  Hope that is clearer now. :)

Comment: @Fravadona that helps a little bit. :p Using `grep -A 1 -i "<SCORE.INTER>" test.sdf | grep -v '^>' >> results` gives me `-41.8551
--
-41.7892
...` so now each value is separated by two hyphens. Any chance to get rid of that as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @lenskapopenska Given your sample data there shouldn't be any double-hyphen in the output

Comment: @Fravadona anyways `grep -A 1 -i "<SCORE.INTER>" test.sdf | grep -v '^>' | grep -v '^--' >> results` worked. So thanks for the advice!

Comment: @lenskapopenska: I've edited my answer in order to contain the final solution. You mighht accept it for reference purposes.

Comment: Yes, indeed that comes close to what I want. Thanks again you two!  Maybe you can give me a final suggestion on how I can merge both files (NAME and SCORES) into one .tsv ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to save the `>  <NAME>` and `>  <SCORE.INTER>` values in a .tsv
> file. Is there any way for a quick solution e.g. via awk?

Your file has `>  <Name>` not `>  <NAME>` (important difference if you match in case-sensitive way). I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way (this assume `> <Name>` is often before `> <SCORE.INTER>` and each `> <SCORE.INTER>` has correpsonding `> <Name>`) let `file.txt` content be

```
ZINC000169748276

 38 39  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   11.2318    3.6419   22.3134 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.5621    3.7685   22.2617 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.0725    5.1806   22.3121 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   10.8850    6.0303   22.4462 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.4310    2.6268   22.1614 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.9848    1.3691   22.0592 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.2548    4.7608   21.1375 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.1479    3.7322   21.1132 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.7728    2.5366   21.8185 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.9539    4.4605   22.4534 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.8873    0.1824   21.9500 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.5117    1.6060   20.8656 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.2544    6.2009   22.3970 N   0  0  0  0  0  0
   10.3635    4.7178   22.4055 N   0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.4254    5.4429   22.2718 N   0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.7646   -0.5167   20.6443 N   0  3  0  0  0  0
    6.5529   -4.6019   19.9460 O   0  5  0  0  0  0
    8.2203   -4.0310   21.8048 O   0  5  0  0  0  0
    6.8149    1.6459   17.3793 O   0  5  0  0  0  0
    5.4231   -2.1179   18.5726 O   0  5  0  0  0  0
   10.1403    7.0090   22.5243 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7155   -3.6365   22.1679 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.6431    1.8811   19.7228 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.0295   -0.6218   20.7059 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.7342    3.0736   22.7475 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.0324    4.2091   21.8626 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.1857    1.9631   19.5323 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.0232   -2.2197   20.5667 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.0081   -0.1966   19.1450 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.8632   -3.7464   21.1697 P   0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.7991    1.4009   18.8725 P   0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.9605   -1.3044   19.7288 P   0  0  0  0  0  0
   15.0444    4.6730   22.2089 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.7148    6.3890   22.3078 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.3405   -1.3642   20.6292 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.0706    0.0896   19.8769 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.7928   -0.7891   20.4667 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.3352    3.5319   21.8055 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  2  0  0  0
  1 14  1  0  0  0
  2  3  1  0  0  0
  2  5  1  0  0  0
  3 13  2  0  0  0
  3 15  1  0  0  0
  4 13  1  0  0  0
  4 14  1  0  0  0
  4 21  2  0  0  0
  5  6  2  0  0  0
  6 11  1  0  0  0
  7  8  1  0  0  0
  7 10  1  0  0  0
  8  9  1  0  0  0
  8 26  1  0  0  0
  9 12  1  0  0  0
  9 25  1  0  0  0
 10 14  1  0  0  0
 10 25  1  0  0  0
 11 16  1  0  0  0
 12 27  1  0  0  0
 17 30  1  0  0  0
 18 30  1  0  0  0
 19 31  1  0  0  0
 20 32  1  0  0  0
 22 30  2  0  0  0
 23 31  2  0  0  0
 24 32  2  0  0  0
 27 31  1  0  0  0
 28 30  1  0  0  0
 28 32  1  0  0  0
 29 31  1  0  0  0
 29 32  1  0  0  0
 15 33  1  0  0  0
 15 34  1  0  0  0
 16 35  1  0  0  0
 16 36  1  0  0  0
 16 37  1  0  0  0
 26 38  1  0  0  0
M  END
>  <CHROM.1>
2.74804207,-114.83879868,178.63419806,-11.86097681,-104.18799792,-175.61867989
-82.60305529,-167.43897154,58.52671946,-50.63759561,-111.24083331,101.74294800
8.69431853,1.29062552,20.98254072,-0.89039136,0.27787279,-3.08051579

>  <Name>
ZINC000169748276

>  <RI>
1.76083e+07


>  <Rbt.Executable>
rbdock/0.1.0

>  <Rbt.Library>
librxdock.so/0.1.0

>  <SCORE>
-41.7582

>  <SCORE.INTER>
-41.8551

>  <SCORE.INTER.CONST>
1

>  <SCORE.INTER.POLAR>
-4.96496

>  <SCORE.INTER.REPUL>
0

>  <SCORE.INTER.ROT>
10

>  <SCORE.INTER.VDW>
-40.3742

>  <SCORE.INTER.norm>
-1.30797

>  <SCORE.INTRA>
0.0969082

>  <SCORE.INTRA.DIHEDRAL>
-5.79141

>  <SCORE.INTRA.DIHEDRAL.0>
19.5819

>  <SCORE.INTRA.POLAR>
0

>  <SCORE.INTRA.POLAR.0>
0

>  <SCORE.INTRA.REPUL>
0

>  <SCORE.INTRA.REPUL.0>
0

>  <SCORE.INTRA.VDW>
2.99261

>  <SCORE.INTRA.VDW.0>
-5.2787

>  <SCORE.INTRA.norm>
0.00302838

>  <SCORE.RESTR>
0

>  <SCORE.RESTR.CAVITY>
0

>  <SCORE.RESTR.norm>
0

>  <SCORE.SYSTEM>
0

>  <SCORE.SYSTEM.CONST>
0

>  <SCORE.SYSTEM.DIHEDRAL>
0

>  <SCORE.SYSTEM.norm>
0

>  <SCORE.heavy>
32

>  <SCORE.norm>
-1.30494

$$$$
```

then

```
awk '/^>  <Name>/{getline;printf "%s\t",$0}/^>  <SCORE\.INTER>/{getline;print $0}' file.txt
```

output

```
ZINC000169748276    -41.8551
```

Explanation: [`getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html) causes GNU `AWK` to load next line, therefore `$0` becomes content of line after current line. When `>  <Name>` at start of line (`^`) is encountered load next line and print it followed by TAB for line starting with `>  <SCORE.INTER>` load next line and print it. Note that `.` needs to be escaped as it has special meaning.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*